# How detect client "socket.close()" in tornado socket server

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, tornado

I am implementing a tornado socket server based on this code:

https://gist.github.com/robcowie/974695

Client is Python simple socket client. When I call `socket.close()` in client, nothing happens in server. I put full `print` traces in the server and closing is not detected nowhere.

I know I can detect the closure for example sending a string "CNNDEND" which means closing. But I wonder if there is any way to detect on server `socket.close()` from client.

Answer (score 0):

in Connection `__init__`:

```
self.stream.set_close_callback(self.__onClose)
```

in Connection class:

```
def __onClose(self):
    print 'close detected'
```